# Not able to use rupee font in a select element in chrome,IE8

Tags: html, css

Not able to use rupee font in a select element in chrome,IE8

Im using a WebRupee to display the indian rupee currency. Font is displayed fine if its within a `<p>` tag but if i put it in a select option element the rupee is displayed properly only in firefox but not in chrome and IE8 (only displays R).

```
<select >
   <option>$</option>
   <option>£</option>
   <option>€</option>
   <option style="font-family:WebRupee;">R</option>
</select>​
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/WEJbc/3/

Comment: You can use this http://cdn.webrupee.com/js . It will replace all Rs to rupee symbol

Comment: yeah tried even in that it wouldn't work in select box, any alternatives ?

Comment: What about ASCII code of rupee symbol &#x20b9;

Answer (score 2):

The INDIAN RUPEE SIGN U+20B9, which this is clearly about, is not ready for prime time on the Internet. Added to Unicode very recently, in version 6.0, it can be expected to be available in several commonly used fonts during the next ten years or so. Then you can use it as such, in UTF-8 encoded documents, or as the character reference `&#x20b9;`.

Meanwhile, use a currency name, or a currency abbreviation, or a currency code, or an existing special symbol like the RUPEE SIGN U+20A8 (₨). In a dropdown menu for currencies, localized names (such as “US dollar”) are best; e.g. the symbol “$” is used to denote dozens of currencies in the world.

Using `<option style="font-family:WebRupee;">R</option>` is a completely wrong approach, as it tries to change the meaning of a character (R) to something else by displaying it using a trick font. See e.g. http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/charset/fontface-harmful.html and http://alis.isoc.org/web_ml/html/fontface.en.html

Technically, for `option` the trick fails even in situations where it might seem to work in some contexts. The reason is that browsers may render `option` elements in a fixed font, disallowing any font change inside.

The trickery could be extended to the `option` elements by setting `select { font-family: WebRupee; }`, because IE lets you change the font of the entire dropdown menu, just not individual options. But in addition to all the problems of font trickery, this would fail because the WebRupee font has been designed so that it lacks the dollar sign ($), so that option would be displayed as empty.